# file overwrite in java -- user-mapped section open error

Tags: java, overwrite

The following function in a java program is written with the intent to read from a file and overwrite back to the same file after.

```
public static void readOverWrite(File dir) throws IOException {
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        String[] data = readFile(f).split("\n");
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                writer.write((data[i]+"\n"));
            }
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The error message on trying to run the program is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\..\data\AQtxt\APW19980807.0261.tml (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at General.SplitCreationDate.splitLine(SplitCreationDate.java:37)
    at General.SplitCreationDate.main(SplitCreationDate.java:53)
```

Request help in resolving the error.

---

Code for readFile

```
protected static String readFile(File fullPath) throws IOException {
    try(FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(fullPath)) {
        FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
        stream.close();
        return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
    }
}
```

---

Read in another thread that this is a windows issue and so MappedByteBuffer in the readFile method was the cause of the problem. Re-wrote the readFile method as below. It works!

```
protected static String readFile(File fullPath) throws IOException {
    String string = "";
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fullPath))) {
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            string += str + "\n";
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Do you have correct file permissions? I've found on goolge a guy that had the same problem but moving to another directory solved it.

Comment: Can we see the code for readFile?

Comment: The file permissions seem fine to me, Jorge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your file streams after opening them, or they will still be around on your system. This can lead to corruption, and errors like this. Review the [Java Learning Tutorials on File I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html). [This tutorial](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42) also shows the way.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadWriteTextFile {

  /**
  * Fetch the entire contents of a text file, and return it in a String.
  * This style of implementation does not throw Exceptions to the caller.
  *
  * @param aFile is a file which already exists and can be read.
  */
  static public String getContents(File aFile) {
    //...checks on aFile are elided
    StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

    try {
      //use buffering, reading one line at a time
      //FileReader always assumes default encoding is OK!
      BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
      try {
        String line = null; //not declared within while loop
        /*
        * readLine is a bit quirky :
        * it returns the content of a line MINUS the newline.
        * it returns null only for the END of the stream.
        * it returns an empty String if two newlines appear in a row.
        */
        while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
          contents.append(line);
          contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
      }
      finally {
        input.close();
      }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return contents.toString();
  }
```

Notice the *finally* block. This ensures that the stream gets closed whether an Exception happens or not. You should use one to close your open streams.

Comment: have tried with closing the open streams...the problem persists. Change included in my code above.

Comment: How are you calling readFile()?

Answer (score 0):

Memory-mappings are not closed when the underlying file is closed. Use another technique to read the file into memory, if you must. It is generally preferable to process files a piece at a time.